# Detect alphabet used in submitted text (forum/blog)

Tags: php

I would like to know the best way to detect the alphabet used when people submit posts on my forum (can be useful for blogs too).
The thing is lately I got a lot of spam in cyrillic alphabet, greek alphabet and japanese, so since my forum is for french and english speaking people, I would like to prevent spammers from posting in different alphabets.
Is it possible with a regular expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is possible to do for instance:

```
preg_match('/([\p{Greek}])+/u', $post);
```

This checks if there is at least 1 greek char.
See here for more information (and other alphabets): http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

It's also possible to do another way, like checking that all chars belong to the Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

You can count a number of characters from the unwanted alphabets. If this number exceeds some limit - drop the message. To count this number you can detect the message encoding from the request, and then use character codes. Btw you can filter your messages by encoding as well.

Comment: Even if I answered to my question, thanks for taking some time to answer.